# Concurrency with EventMachine for a high performance need

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rubygems, eventmachine

I need a high performance network tcp server. I wrote this code in EventMachine.

```
class ReactingServer < EventMachine::Connection
  attr_accessor :packet, :packet_class
  @@packet_count = 0

  def initialize(packet_class)
    super
    @packet_class = eval(packet_class)
    @packet = @packet_class.new
    @@packet_count = 0
  end

  def receive_data(data)
    @packet.clear

    operation = proc do
      @packet.read(data)
      @@packet_count = @@packet_count +1
    end

    call_back = proc do
      puts @packet.inspect
      puts "-------------------#{@@packet_count}------------------------\n"
    end
    EventMachine.defer operation, call_back
  end
end
```

Then i wrote a ruby client.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'socket'

sock = TCPSocket.new("192.168.15.5", 8181)

500.times do |n|
    packet = "\x00\x01\x1\x0\x1FNazar Hu\x00\x0F\xF\xF\xF\xF\xF\xF"
    sock.send packet, 0
  sleep 0.01
end
```

The first problem i am facing is that, if i remove `sleep` from client many of the packets can't be received on server end. If i send 5 packets, on average 3 packets are received. Why this is been happening.

Other question is that my server needed to server around `20K` connection and on average 10 connections would be sending packets to server per second. Does `EventMachine` is capable of handling this kind of load?

Comment: 20,000 simultaneous connections on one server is *a lot* of connections.

Comment: You can say that 20,000 connections would not be true. I actually want to say that it have to server `20K` clients. Each client would send request to server every `10 minute` and on average 10 clients would send packet every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a neat article http://www.slideshare.net/igrigorik/ruby-c10k-high-performance-networking-rubykaigi-09

I don't know what your main block looks like, but have you tried adding epoll to the beginning of your event_machine::server ?

```
EM.epoll
trap("TERM") { EM.stop }
trap("INT")  { EM.stop }
EM.run do
  EM.start_server("0.0.0.0", 8181, ReactingServer, "PacketClass") do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Also, that eval looks a little funny. Can you change `"PacketClass"` to `:class => PacketClass` instead?

I'm guessing here at what your code looks like.

Answer (score 2):

`receive_data` is not called each time someone is sending something to the socket, it's buffered. And `data` size may differ from your several bytes to several KB. It's your responsibility to properly parse data. Two things you can be sure of is that all data which is sent will be received and the order will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [goliath](http://www.igvita.com/2011/03/08/goliath-non-blocking-ruby-19-web-server/)? It is based on EventMachine and fibers. It is reported that it can serve up to 3000 req/s.

Comment: Does `Goliath` works for `TCP` and `UDP` as well. Serving more than `20` ports at the same time?

Comment: Both of the answers are NO I'm afraid.